# Managing dependency graph via mixins in scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, mixins

I have a class which required 2 traits both of which require the same trait. How do i go about adding it in this context

```
class RandomTest extends AbstractTestCase {
  "asdasd" should "asdsda" in {
    val a = new Application with XYZAppName with Session with MetricsPublisher

    a.a()
  }

  abstract class Application extends Session with MetricsPublisher {

    println("Application")
    def a() : Unit = { println("application.a")}
  }



  trait RequiredAppContext {
    println("RequiredAppContext")
    val appName : String
  }

  trait MetricsPublisher extends RequiredAppContext {
    this:RequiredAppContext =>
    println("MetricsPublisher")
  }
  trait Session extends RequiredAppContext{
    this:RequiredAppContext =>
    println("Session")
    lazy val appNameoverload = func(appName)
    def func(value:String ) {println("appNameoverload "+appName)}

  }


  // implmentations
  trait XYZAppName extends RequiredAppContext {
    println("XYZAppName")
    override val appName = "xyz"
  }
}
```

Here is the output to this program :

```
 [scalatest] RequiredAppContext 
 [scalatest] Session 
 [scalatest] MetricsPublisher 
 [scalatest] Application 
 [scalatest] XYZAppName
 [scalatest] application.a
```

What is the best way to move XYZAppName initialization to appear before Session ?

Answer (score 1):

Scala's linearization algorithm, managing trait graph initialization order and solving diamond inheritance problem, traverses (acyclic) inheritance graph in declaration order, satisfying requirements to initialize parent node, but omitting all duplicates that was already initialized. The catch here is that to initialize some class, you need to initialize its base class first, along with all traits that extend it. Scala won't even allow to specify base class in any position after `extends` or `new` other than first - you can only add traits using `with`. For the (anonymous) class of `a` base class is `Application`:

```
a.type
  -> Application
    -> Session
      -> RequiredAppContext
    -> MetricsPublisher
      -> RequiredAppContext // omitted
  -> XYZAppName
    -> RequiredAppContext  // omitted
  -> Session // omitted
    -> RequiredAppContext  // parent omitted
  -> MetricsPublisher // omitted
    -> RequiredAppContext  // parent omitted
```

So your only option is to modify your inheritance hierarchy, turning `Application` to trait and reordering it with `XYZAppName` in the definition of `a`:

```
trait Application extends Session with MetricsPublisher
...
val a = new XYZAppName with Application with Session with MetricsPublisher
// RequiredAppContext
// XYZAppName
// Session
// MetricsPublisher
// Application
```

That solution, however, cannot cover all possible situations - if your abstract class have constructor, you cannot turn it into a trait (there's [ongoing work](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/trait-parameters.html) to allow trait parameters in future versions of Scala, but it's far from being finished). It's also not an option if the base class is defined in external code.